# ModuleNotFoundError while using GitHub codespace editor

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, codespaces, github-codespaces

Recently I started using GitHub codespace for the first time. I created a new codespace from one of my repositories. Assuming the folder structure as below:

```
my-codespace
|--- utils
|------ my_script.py
|--- config.py
```

I get the following error when I import `config.py` inside `my_script.py`:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

Autocomplete is working inside the editor, and it recognizes `config.py` while I try to import it

[image]

After a while red line appears indicating an error

[image]

All methods, classes, and variables belonging to `config.py` are available inside `my_script.py` by autocomplete.

Currently, I'm using PyCharm on my computer and have no issues with that repository but I get the same error when I run it on local VS Code.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me in this regard.

Comment: Which folder do you open in vscode?

Comment: @JialeDu I opened the root folder my-codespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of research and inquiry, I was able to solve most of the problems. I will update this post whenever I find out the answer to the remaining part.

As I said in the original post, this issue exists in both local and GitHub versions of VS Code. Someone suggested setting `PYTHONPATH` to the path of my custom module (`config.py` here). This might work for you, but it didn't work for me. If you prefer to do that, you can run the following to make sure the path is set correctly:

```
import os
print(os.environ)
```

For the local version, I solved the problem by doing these:

- Adding the following lines to the `\user\settings.json` file made Python  script files in subfolders find my custom module in the root folder:

  ```
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
  "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
  }
  ```

  Note that I'm running my code on a Windows machine. If you are using Linux-based machines, you should use `"terminal.integrated.env.linux"` instead.
- I also created a `.env` (no filename, just an extension) file inside the root folder, and then I added `PYTHONPATH=Y:\Programming\my-codespace` to it. By doing this, Jupyter notebooks are also able to find custom modules inside subfolders. If you prefer to use any other file name say `vscode.env` you can change it inside the application settings.

Obviously, you will need to reload your VS Code window after applying these changes. Just press CTRL+SHIFT+P and type reload window.

For the GitHub codespace version, I tried to do the same things as above:

- I added the Linux version (`terminal.integrated.env.linux`) to the `settings.json` file to make Python script files in subfolders work without any issues.
- Adding `PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${workspaceFolder}` (`${workspaceFolder}` is the alias for the project's root folder) to the `.env` file **didn't help to run Jupyter notebooks inside the subfolders and I got an importing error as before.** This is the remaining unresolved part of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I create a test file with the following structure and open the **my-codespace** folder in vscode.

```
my-codespace
├─ config.py
└─ utils
   └─ my_script.py
```

[image]

To fix the above error, add the following code at the top of the ***my_script.py*** file.

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("./")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Adding those two lines didn't help however, I added `"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"}` to `settings.json` file in my local editor and it resolved. On the codespace editor, I added the Linux version and it worked too. But the problem still exists when working with Jupyter notebooks in both editors.